# Contributing to others pull request by pulling their branch

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull

My co-worker has raised a pull request to a repo to which I'm also a member.For this PR he has to make changes.Unfortunately my co-worker is no more in my project and now I need to make changes and commit the changes to this PR(The PR which is raised by co-worker).

I know this could be done by pulling his branch and raising a PR to his branch.But this will not work as he is no more in my team.

Is there Any way that I can achieve this??.

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 1):

> I know this could be done by pulling his branch and raising a PR to his branch.But this will not work as he is no more in my team.

For pulling his branch: "[Checking out pull requests locally](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/)"

```
git remote add hisForl /url/of/his/fork
git fetch hisFork pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
```

It will work, except you would be pushing your own branch (that you can make with a different name: `git checkout -b myBranch hisFork/BRANCHNAME`), and make a new PR from that new branch.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Get the latest version of the branch the pull request is about.
2. Create a new branch for this branch
3. Make necessary changes in the new branch
4. Push the new branch
5. Create a new pull request in your name from the new branch.

Comment: That is exactly what I was saying.

Comment: @VonC - fair dinkum. I just spelt it out in steps.

Comment: "fair dinkum"... I was not familiar with this Australian slang :)